# ng-show does not re-evaluate on route change

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to switch between toolbars when a user moves from being **logged out** to **logged in** but ng-show does not appear to re-evaluate on route change.

This is my code so far

```
      <div ng-controller="MainController as vm" ng-show="vm.currentPath === '/'">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#/signup">Sign up</a></li>
          <li><a href="#/login">Log in</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div ng-controller="BuilderController as vm" ng-show="vm.currentPath === '/builder'">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#/home" ng-click="vm.logout()">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

And in the MainController and BuilderController I have:

```
var vm = this;
vm.currentPath = $location.path();
```

Comment: `vm.currentPath = $location.path();` is executed only once, when your controller is instantiated, thus doesn't change later on, that's why your `ng-show` doesn't re-evaluate. One simple solution is to have following expression in `ng-show` - `$location.path() === '/'`. Better option is to have a custom handler for click event on tab links.

Comment: I tried `ng-show="$location.path() === '/'"`, but it doesn't seem to work, I just get an empty div element.

Comment: have you bind `$location` to controller's variable? It looks like this should work: https://plnkr.co/edit/d9US3wt6CR5gjnLKUPbU?p=preview. I slightly modified your example for the purpose of a demo. By the way, default `$location.path()` is `''` not `'/'`.

Comment: Thanks, it works now!